# How to bypass Laravel Exception handling

Tags: php, exception, symfony, laravel, guzzle

I have a method that checks if a user has valid Session info. This is supposed to throw an Exception, `Guzzle\Http\Exception\BadResponseException` but when I try to catch it :

```
catch (Guzzle\Http\Exception\BadResponseException $e) 
{
    return false;
} 
return true
```

Laravel doesn't get to this code and immediately starts it's own error handling. And ideas on how to bypass Laravels own implementation and use my own Catch.

EDIT: I just found out Laravel uses the same Exception handler as Symfony, so I also added the Symfony2 tag.

EDIT 2:

I sort of fixed the issue by disabling Guzzle exceptions and checking the return header manually. It's a bit of a short cut but in this case, it does the job. Thanks for the responses!

Comment: Can you post more relevant code (including `try` block)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually this exception can be catched in Laravel, you just have to respect (and understand)  namespacing:

If you have

```
namespace App;
```

and you do

```
catch (Guzzle\Http\Exception\BadResponseException $e)
```

PHP understands that you are trying to

```
catch (\App\Guzzle\Http\Exception\BadResponseException $e)
```

So, for it to work you just need a root slash:

```
catch (\Guzzle\Http\Exception\BadResponseException $e)
```

And it will work.

Comment: Wow!! So you should mind namespacing catch(Exception e) won't work it should be catch(\Exception e)

Answer (score 2):

By default, the `app/start/global.php` file contains an error handler for all exceptions. However, you may specify more handlers if needed. Handlers are called based on the `type-hint` of the Exception they handle. For example, you may create a handler that only handles your `BadResponseException` instances, like

```
App::error(function(Guzzle\Http\Exception\BadResponseException $exception)
{
    // Handle the exception...
    return Response::make('Error! ' . $exception->getCode());
});
```

Also, make sure you have a well defined (`BadResponseException`) class. Read more on [Laravel Documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/errors#handling-errors).

Comment: **Note:** that Laravel will continue to pass the responsibility of handling the error to its registered handlers until one returns a `Response` object.

Laravel uses the [Chain of Responsibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern) pattern when handling errors.

This lets you handle the error any way you choose. You can do something like log the Guzzle error, and then let Laravel's other error handlers decide how to respond. 

See [this blog post](http://fideloper.com/laravel4-error-handling "laravel error handling") for some more explanation.

Comment: This is not an answer to "how to bypass it?" and handle the exception in my method right after I called something that might throw some exceptions. Why should I write code outside my class to handle things that my class know how to handle? Take a look at some Sentry's Cartalyst examples: http://docs.cartalyst.com/sentry-2/authentication/login. Those are stuff that will never work on Laravel.

Comment: @AntonioCarlosRibeiro, the question I thought about how to register your own error handling, am I wrong ?

Comment: As he/she says "but when I try to catch it:". Imo, as the code shows, he's trying to catch the exception in a method which cannot succeed because Laravel catches it before anything else.

Comment: @AntonioCarlosRibeiro, OH! i see now, `OP` is using `try catch` in the class itself.

Comment: @AntonioCarlosRibeiro did you managed to bypass Laravel Exception handling, as I also support your concept of handling exceptions in the method itself and returning response from there only, instead of keeping all the exception handling at a common place.

Comment: Yes I did, and just added an answer here to show how.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of your code

```
catch (Guzzle\Http\Exception\BadResponseException $e) 
{
   return false;
} 
return true
```

use this solution

```
catch (\Exception $e) 
{
   return false;
} 
return true
```

to catch all possible exceptions thrown by Guzzle.

If you explicitly want to catch a *BadResponseException* you can also prepend your exception's class namespace with **'\'**.

```
catch (\Guzzle\Http\Exception\BadResponseException $e) 
{
   return false;
} 
return true
```