# How would I go about refactoring this controller by extracting some of the code out?

Tags: php, laravel, refactoring, laravel-4

```
public function store()
{
  $input = Input::all();
  $validator = User::validate($input);

  if(!$validator->passes()) {
    $notification['danger'] = 'There were validation errors!';
    return Redirect::route('user.create')->withInput()->withErrors($validator)->with('notification', $notification);
  }

  $input['password'] = Hash::make($input['password']);
  $user = $this->user->create($input);
  $role = $this->role->find($input['role_id']);
  $user->roles()->save($role);

  $notification['success'] = "User $user->email sucessfuly created.";
  return Redirect::route('user.index')->with('notification', $notification);    
}
```

So I've been reading a lot about architecture and while I realize this is not the "good" way of doing things, I can't think of a lot of solutions.

Extracting this into a bunch of classes like UserRepository UserFormValidator etc sounds like overengineering, specifically in my case, where it's a rather small project, that will only last for a few weeks.

What I'm more interested about is how I would go about extracting this business logic into my User model. Associating other models through relationships is in my opinion a concern of the model anyway. My current model code only sets up relationships like hasMany(), belongsTo() etc. and $filleable, $hidden properties.

Anyway, I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before repositories this was how I used to create and validate my models:

```
public function store()
{
    $user = new User(Input::all());

    $user->password = Input::get('password');

    if( !$user->save() ) {
        return Redirect::back()
                ->withInput()
                ->withErrors($user->errors);
    }

    return Redirect::route('users.index')
        ->with('successMessages', 'User "'.$user->first_name.'" created.');
}
```

And this code is provided by

A BaseModel:

```
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class BaseModel extends Eloquent {

    public $errors;

    public function __construct(array $attributes = array()) {

        parent::__construct($attributes);

    }

    public static function boot() {
        parent::boot();

        static::saving(function ($data) {
            return $data->validate();
        });
    }

    public function validate() {

        $validation = Validator::make($this->attributes, $this->rules);

        if($validation->passes()) return true;

        $this->errors = $validation->messages();

        return false;

    }

}
```

By creating a saving event on boot, you can validate your models and return true or false on save();

A User Model:

```
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends BaseModel implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {
    protected $table = 'users';

    public $guarded =   [   
                            'password',
                            'password_confirmation',
                        ];

    public $rules = array(
                            'first_name' => 'required|min:3',
                            'last_name' => 'required|min:3',
                            'email' => 'required|min:6',
                        );

    protected $hidden = array('password');

    public function setPasswordAttribute($string) 
    {

        $this->attributes['password'] = Hash::make($string);
    }

}
```

And some code on my `layout.blade.php`:

```
@if( Session::has('errors') )
    You have some errors:

    @foreach( Session::get('errors')->all() as $error )
        <div class="alert alert-block alert-error fade in">
            <button data-dismiss="alert" class="close" type="button">×</button>
            <p>{{ $error->message }}</p>
        </div>
    @endforeach
@endif

@if( isset($successMessage) ) 
    <div class="alert alert-block alert-success fade in">
        <button data-dismiss="alert" class="close" type="button">×</button>
        <p>{{ $successMessage }}</p>
    </div>
@endif

@if( isset($errorMessage) ) 
    <div class="alert alert-block alert-error fade in">
        <button data-dismiss="alert" class="close" type="button">×</button>
        <p>{{ $errorMessage }}</p>
    </div>
@endif
```

Actually, this blade code is not that big, it's provided by some blade _partials and a Template helper class and look a little more like this:

```
{{ Template::notifications('error', Session::get('errors')) }}
{{ isset($successMessage) ? Template::notify('success', $successMessage) : '' }}
{{ isset($errorMessage) ? Template::notify('error', $errorMessage) : '' }}
```

Using validation this you save some lines and will never need to remember to validate your input again.

Comment: this is the so called self-validating model way of doing things right? This is actually one of the ways I was considering to go for. Since you know about repositories, do you think they're "worth it" in projects of any size? I'm currently working on a first prototype / minimum viable product for a client and I'm not sure if the whole SOLID / unit testing / design patterns package is realistic in "all" cases.

Answer (score 0):

Because this is a small project and you are thinking about moving code into the User model, here is a chunk of code that could be re-factored:

Instead of:

```
  $role = $this->role->find($input['role_id']);
  $user->roles()->save($role);
```

Write:

```
       $role = $this->role->find($input['role_id']);
       $user->addRole($role);
```

and in your User model:

```
class User extends Eloquent
{
   public function addRole($role)
   {
          if(!is_null($role) and is_object($role) and $role->id > 0)
          {
              return    $this->roles()->save($role);
          }
          else
          {
               throw new RoleNotFoundException($role);
          }
   }
}
```

And then in your global.php file define an error handler for this type of exception:

```
App::error(function(RoleNotFoundException $exception)
{
    // Handle the exception...
    return Response::make('Error! ' . $exception->getCode());
});
```

This will make your code more readable and more robust, and will save you from remembering the specifics of Laravel when implementing methods and this is why you are wrapping them in the User model. It is fairly simple in this example, but this approach can save you a lot of headaches in more complex scenarios.

Comment: Try/Catch on Laravel will not work, this is not how it works. Take a look at this answer to understand it better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19360215/how-to-bypass-laravel-exception-handling/19372517?noredirect=1#comment28738114_19372517.

Comment: Thanks, Antonio, I did not know that Try/Catch would not work at all. Actually the code looks even cleaner without it - perhaps that is the whole point of defining an error handler in a separate file.